# jQuery.get() method return value and assign to global variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a function in JS with a JQuery method, inside a script in HTML which gets data from a .txt.

In this .txt I have one line of text like this:

```
Test_1_NoOk
```

In the function, I make a split() and get the character "1" in a variable, as shown below.

```
$.get("Text.txt", function(data) {

var parts= data.split('_');
fail= parseInt(parts[1]);

});
```

After processing this information, I want the global variable "fail" to get that "1" and be painted in HTML division.

But when I paint it, it always stays like "0", because the value at the initialization of the varibale is that (it doesn't change).

Any way to overwrite the value of the global one, inside the function?

Comment: you said `fail` but your assigning it to a variable `errores`

Comment: First thing i would do is to add this line in the start of your `$.get`. `console.log(data)`. then look in your log and see if it returns what it shall

Comment: when do you output it to html? you should try moving it to the request callback function

Comment: `$.get` is asynchronous, therefore you need to work with the response within the callback. Otherwise the value may not yet be set. See the duplicate questions I marked for more information

Comment: @Roljhon my mistake, editted.

Comment: @TomaszRup I output  it in a div of th HTML with the sentence:             `document.write(fail);`